# How can I save the texts I have extracted with OCR from different images in multiple .txt files

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I made an OCR program using the Python programming language and the tesserOCR library. In the program I have made, I scan all the pictures in a folder and extract the texts in them. But these extracted texts are saved in a single .txt file. How can I save the texts in each image to different .txt files. That is, the texts in each image should be saved as a .txt file named after that image.

`

```
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image
import glob
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
api = tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI(path='D:/Anaconda/Tesseract5/tessdata', lang='tur')

files = glob.glob('C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/OCR/wpp/*')
filesProcessed = []

def extract():
    for f, file in enumerate(files):
        if f >= 0:
            try:
                text = ' '
                jpegs = glob.glob('C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/OCR/wpp/*')
                jpegs = sorted(jpegs)
                print(len(jpegs))
                for i in jpegs:
                    pil_image = Image.open(i)
                    api.SetImage(pil_image)
                    text = text + api.GetUTF8Text()
                filename = file[:-4] + '.txt'
                with open(filename, 'w') as n:
                    n.write(text)
            except:
                print(f'{file} is a corrupt file')
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    extract()
```

`

Texts from all images are saved in the same .txt file. I want it to be saved in different .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a version of your `extract` function where I removed all the stuff unrelated to writing to a file, and it writes a file for every single file in `files`.

```
def extract():
    from os.path import splitext
    for file in files:
        try:
            with open(splitext(file)[0] + ".txt", 'w') as n:
                n.write(" ")
        except:
            print(f'{file} is a corrupt file')
            break
```

Comment: when i run your code only the last image is saved as .txt file.

Comment: Have you tried checking the length/content of `files`?

Comment: my friend, I ran the code you wrote, but it was not correct. My request is to save the text files I received with ocr as different .txt files. That is, to save the texts in the 1st image as a 1.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Currently the texts in all images are saved in different .txt files.

```
def extract():

jpegs = glob.glob('C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/OCR/wpp/*')
jpegs = sorted(jpegs)
print(len(jpegs))
n = len(jpegs)

for i in range(0, n):
    img = Image.open(jpegs[i])
    api.SetImage(img)
    text = api.GetUTF8Text()
    print(i + 1)
    filename = open(f'wpptext/text{i + 1}.txt', "+w")
    filename.write(text)
```